# Reversing a single linked list will only output the first entry (java

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse

I am currently trying to reverse a single linked list through this algorithm:

```
public void reverse() {
    Node before = null;
    Node current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        Node next = current.getNext();
        before = current;
        current = next;
    }
    first = before;
    }
```

I suspect the issue lies with the swapping of before and current.getNext(), but can't seem to figure it out.

For example, when I input 1 2 3, I receive 3 as an output, but not 3 2 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: For those of you asking for more details on the code:

```
class Node {
private int data;
private Node next;

public Node(int newData) {
    data = newData;
    next = null;
}

public void setNext(Node nextElem) {
    next = nextElem;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public int getData() {
    return data;
}
}

class Element {
public Node first, last;

public void append(int value)
{
    Node newElement = new Node(value);
    if (first == null)
        first = newElement;
    else
        last.setNext(newElement);
    last = newElement;
}

public void output(){
    for (Node current = first; current != null; current = current.getNext())
        System.out.print(current.getData() + " -> ");
    System.out.println();
}

public void reverse() { //the only part I am supposed to change/implement
    Node before = null;
    Node current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        Node next = current.getNext();
        before = current;
        current = next;
    }
    first = before;
    }
}

class LElement {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    Element list = new Element();

    while (scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        list.append(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    list.output();
    list.reverse();
    list.output();

    scanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: You never set any values on your nodes, this code essentially does nothing...

Comment: Originally I had wanted to set current.getNext() = before; before = current; etc... but since only a variable can be on the left I don't know what to do. I obviously do know that the code isn't working.

Comment: Your approach was correct, but you need a `setNext()` method or use an existing `add` method

Comment: @Soana Could you elaborate on the setNext() method? I am very new to java and am very much stuck in the newb phase.

Comment: Did you program the `Node` class yourself? If not, where is it from?

Comment: @Soana This is the original Node class, which was given as part of the skeleton code:     Node(int newData) {
  data = newData;
  next = null;

Comment: @NinaHain what @Soana meant is that you need to use a mutator method in the Node class that sets the next node.  In this case you would do something like `current.setNext(before)` before you set `before = current`

Comment: @mstbaum Thanks for the respond, however we are not supposed to edit the skeleton code and are only supposed to change the actual method. I will post the full skeleton code as an edit.

Comment: @NinaHain there's a `setNext()` in the skeleton code!

Comment: @mstbaum What mistake am I making and where should I correct it with the help of setNext()?

Comment: From my previous comment: *`current.setNext(before)` before `before = current`*

Comment: @mstbaum I tried it in between like this: Node next = current.getNext();
   current.setNext(before);
   before = current; and I am getting a runtime error. Any ideas?

Comment: @mstbaum Thanks a ton! My error was actually a missing scope, no idea how that managed to get in there. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void reverse() {
    Node before = null;
    Node current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        Node next = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(before); ////
        before = current;
        current = next;
    }
    first = before;
}
```

Better readable with nicer naming:

```
public void reverse() {
    Node reversedList = null;
    Node current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        Node next = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(reversedList); ////
        reversedList = current;
        current = next;
    }
    first = reversedList;
}
```